# Xubuntu save multi monitor config

Tags: xubuntu, multiple-monitors, display

I've a multi-monitor-setup with 2 screens (3 with the notebook T460s itself) on xubuntu 16.04 at a DP KVM-Switch. The notebook is connected via the Dock-3 Docking Station over 2 DP-Ports.

Every time I switch from Desktop to Laptop the monitor configuration is lost, so I've to configure it from scratch including activation of the single monitors. Is there a way to save these configuration and restore it automatically if the notebook is connected with the docking station?

The (shortened) output of `xrandr` with the screens connected:

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 6800 x 1440, maximum 32767 x 32767
eDP1 connected 2560x1440+4240+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 310mm x 170mm
   2560x1440     60.00*+  48.00  
   1920x1440     60.00  

   .........

DP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP2-1 connected 1680x1050+2560+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 473mm x 296mm
   1680x1050     59.88*+  59.95  
   1920x1080     60.00    50.00    59.94  

   ..........

DP2-2 connected primary 2560x1440+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 527mm x 296mm
   2560x1440     59.95*+
   1920x1200     59.95  

   ..........

DP2-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Comment: xrandr returns the following:

http://pastebin.com/41pGtbHF

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Not 16.04 specific

The issue you are facing is not exclusive to 16.04, it happens on many Ubuntu versions.

#### How to solve

Reading your output of `xrandr`, and assuming I made no typo, the following command should arrange your screens the way you set it up:

```bsh
xrandr --output DP2-2 --auto --pos 0x0 --output DP2-1 --auto --pos 2560x0 --output eDP1 --auto --pos 4240x0
```

The quickest and easiest solution is to add it to a shortcut key: Settings > Keyboard > Application Shortcuts. Then press the shortcut after the screens are connected.

#### Explanation

From the output of `xrandr`, we can see the information on the three connected screens:

```
eDP1 connected 2560x1440+4240+0
DP2-1 connected 1680x1050+2560+0
DP2-2 connected primary 2560x1440+0+0
```

In the last section(s): `2560x1440+4240+0`, in the part: `+4240+0`, we can see the position of the screen in the whole picture of combined screens (x,y). From left to right, the screens then are obviously arranged like:

```
DP2-2 +0+0 | DP2-1 +2560+0 | eDP1 +4240+0
```

[image]

If this arrangement is not remembered automatically, we can set it up with the command I added at the beginning of this answer.

The option `--auto` I added, since you mentioned having to also *activate* the screens.

### EDIT

As requested, a small bash script to run in the background to make the setup if the screens are connected:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

let "target = 3"
swon=false

function nscreens {
    curr=$(xrandr | grep " connected" | wc -l)
}

function setup_scr {
    xrandr --output DP2-1 --auto --pos 0x0 \
    --output DP2-2 --auto --pos 2560x0 \
    --output eDP1 --auto --pos 4240x0
}

while true
do
  sleep 4
  nscreens
  if [ "$curr" -eq "$target" ] && [ "$swon" == false ]
  then
    setup_scr
    swon=true
  elif [ "$curr" -ne "$target" ] && [ "$swon" == true ]
  then
    swon=false
  fi
done
```

- Copy the script into an empty file, save it as `setup_scr.sh`, make it executable
- Test- run it in a terminal with the command:

  ```
  /path/to/setup_scr.sh
  ```

  connect/disconnect the screens
- if it works fine, add it to startup applications: Dash > Startup Applications > Add. Add the command:

  ```
  /bin/bash -c "sleep 15 && /path/to/setup_scr.sh"
  ```

#### Explanation

- Once per 4 seconds, the script counts the number of connected screens. If it equals 3, it runs the setup a single time, remembering it did set the screens by switching the value of "swon" (switched on) to `true`.

  Then if the number of screens is no longer equal to 3, "swon" is set to `false` again, and so on.

#### Note

I tested the script on my two- screen setup, and it worked fine, however, there is always the possibility I made a typo somewhere, and obviously I could not test it on your system. In case of an error, please mention.

Comment: Perfect. Something got weired with the positions, but with your perfect explanation I could correct this. The command is now:

xrandr --output DP2-1 --auto --pos 0x0 --output DP2-2 --auto --pos 2560x0 --output eDP1 --auto --pos 4240x0

Is there a way to execute this command automatically if some of the screens or the docking station gets recognized?

Comment: @Atomius perfect, I was hoping you'd ask :). If I get home, I will add it to the answer today or tomorrow :)

Comment: Hi there, I have adapted the scripts to my needs and it does exacly what it should. The problem is that each time the check occurs my mouse freezes for like half second. I assume it is using the main gui thread for this? Is there a way to make the script be less preemptive?

Answer (score 5):

these answer are only about restoring. To "save" the current state you could use this scrip (dump_randr.sh)

```
#!/bin/bash
fileName="$1"
while read -r line; do
    IFS=" "
    entry=( $line )
    display=${entry[0]}
    IFS="x+"
    if [[ "${entry[2]}" == primary ]]; then
        primary=1
        measurement=( ${entry[3]} )
    else
        primary=0
        measurement=( ${entry[2]} )
    fi
    unset IFS
    width=${measurement[0]}
    height=${measurement[1]}
    left=${measurement[2]}
    top=${measurement[3]}

    xrandrOpt="$xrandrOpt --output $display --mode ${width}x${height} --pos ${left}x${top}"
    ((primary)) && xrandrOpt="$xrandrOpt --primary"

done < <(xrandr | grep " connected")

echo "#!/bin/bash" > "$fileName"
echo "xrandr $xrandrOpt" > "$fileName"
chmod +x "$fileName"
```

This will dump the current xrandr options to use them again.
You can do something like this to store the current setup:

```
dump_randr.sh 2_monitors_home.sh
```

which creates `2_monitors_home.sh` to restore the current state.

Comment: Nice script. I would only add that if the monitor needs to be turned on, one needs to manually add the `--auto` flag.

Comment: Thanks for this script! If a monitor is rotated, the output file should be changed so that the dimensions are switched (this script produces `1080x1920` instead of `1920x1080`) and `--rotate left` needs to be added.

Comment: Fantastic script, only change I made is at ln27: `echo "xrandr $xrandrOpt" >> "$fileName"`

Comment: Rotated monitors will also need to have their resolutions fixed.  This script generates `--mode 1200x1920` for one of mine, and instead it needs to be `--mode 1920x1200 --rotate left`

Answer (score 1):

I tried the method proposed by Jacob Vlijm, which I of course edited for my scenario. It did not quite work and for some reason any xrand command which had --auto or --pos in it crashed my machine (Im using Xubuntu 16.04)

Here is my solution to this

```
xrandr --output HDMI1 --mode 1920x1080 --pos 0x0 --rate 60.00 --output eDP1 --off
```

this takes my secondary display that I have connected over HDMI and sets it to 1080p 60Hz while disabling my laptop display

```
xrandr --output eDP1 --mode 1366x768 --pos 0x0 --rate 60.00
```

this sets my laptop display to its native resolution 1366x768 60Hz

I use the first setup when I am connected to 2 displays and I use the second setup when I am connected to only my laptop display.

Here is my setup_scr.sh file:

```
#!/bin/bash

let "target = 2"
swon=false

function nscreens 
{
        curr=$(xrandr | grep " connected" | wc -l)
}

function setup_dubai 
{
    xrandr --output HDMI1 --mode 1920x1080 --pos 0x0 --rate 60.00 --output eDP1 --off
}

function setup_normal 
{
    xrandr --output eDP1 --mode 1366x768 --pos 0x0 --rate 60.00
}

while true
do
  sleep 4
    nscreens
  if [ "$curr" -eq "$target" ] && [ "$swon" == false ]
  then
    setup_dubai
    swon=true
  elif [ "$curr" -ne "$target" ] && [ "$swon" == true ]
  then
    swon=false
    setup_normal
  fi
done
```

Thank you to [Jacob Vlijm](https://askubuntu.com/users/72216/jacob-vlijm) for making this setup real simple with his good explanation